# Programmatically Defined Constraints Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uicollectionview, constraints

I have a `UICollectionView`. I also have the following view which I generate in code:

```
let messageInputContainerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return view
}()
```

Now, I want to add the `messageInputContainerView` so that it is attached to the bottom of the screen, and the `UICollectionView` is directly above it. At the moment I have the following constraints :

```
view.addSubview(messageInputContainerView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: messageInputContainerView)
    view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(48)]", views: messageInputContainerView)

    bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageInputContainerView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint!)
```

The problem is that the collectionView is now touching the bottom of the screen as well, and the two views overlap. I tried solving this with the following constraint :

```
let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageInputContainerView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.collectionView! , attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

view.addConstraint(newConstraint)
```

however this just through a bunch of errors :

```html
016-05-30 19:50:26.153 City[1858:79868] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
 Try this: 
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
 (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fece04d10e0 h=-&- v=-&- UICollectionView:0x7fece08c0a00.midY == UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView:0x7fece04125f0.midY>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fece04d1150 h=-&- v=-&- UICollectionView:0x7fece08c0a00.height == UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView:0x7fece04125f0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece049a460 V:[UIView:0x7fece04992d0(48)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece04d7620 UIView:0x7fece04992d0.bottom == UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView:0x7fece04125f0.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece04a9990 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fece08c0a00]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fece04992d0]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece04a9990 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fece08c0a00]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fece04992d0]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: In case you are supporting iOS9 and up - I would REALLY advise you to look into `NSLayoutAnchor` class, which will allow you to write constraints programmatically MUCH easier.

Comment: To write constraints directly using NSLayoutConstraint and stringified format is not a good idea. Try to use https://github.com/robb/Cartography which has friendlier interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please checkout the basic [tutorials](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) for autolayout. It will simply give You the needed background for IB and constraints.

The debug log commonly all you need - it tells You the exact info for your problem. Let's think about it in detail

```
NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece04a9990 V:[UICollectionView:0x7fece08c0a00]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fece04992d0]
```

`UICollectionView:0x7fece08c0a00` - it's your collection view, it's simple
`UIView:0x7fece04992d0` - it's your messageInputContainerView - that's clear from the following constraint:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fece049a460 V:[UIView:0x7fece04992d0(48)]>"
```

which generated by this line of code:

```
view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(48)]", views: messageInputContainerView)
```

So, if you can see - uicollection view has NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint - so, those one were generated by default. You have two ways - set up your collection view constraints via IB - set leading, trainling, top (to whatever value you need) and bottom constraint with the value 48.

The second one - remove autogenerated constraint programmatically and add new one, as following:

```
[collectionView removeConstraints: [collectionView constraints]]; 
        // top constraint
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.collectionView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    // leading constraint
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.collectionView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    // trailing constaint
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.collectionView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    // your constraint
    let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageInputContainerView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.collectionView! , attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    view.addConstraint(newConstraint)
```

Hope this helps.